# Can broken stopwatch build into Zhonya?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that the stopwatch has a one-time use, and if you try to buy another, they're going to be broken stopwatches.

This item is required to build Zhonya's Hourglass. Can you still use the broken one to build into Zhonya's or do you get stuck being unable to get the final item?

Comment: Stop watch can be forged into a Guardian angel as well. The stop watch functionality itself doesn't prevent forging items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Played a Zyra game just today, and yep, a used Stopwatch just transforms into a Broken Stopwatch, which is still used to build into Zhonya's.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Stopwatch